# loop through adding values in a range (5x5 for example) of row and columns in multiple sheets and dump in one particular sheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have multiple sheets in a single workbook with values in 5 rows and 5 columns in each sheet. I need to add the corresponding cell values (eg: D5) in each sheet and dump it in a new sheet in its D5. I could do it for one particular cell, but I'm confused on how to do it in nested for loops. I've only been doing vba for a day.. so please help. Thanks.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i, val
    'Select worksheets
    For i = 7 To Sheets.Count
        val = val + Sheets(i).Range("e6")
    Next
    Sheets("Summation").Range("e6") = val

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact range address?

Comment: in a particular row it has to go from column B to E in Sheets 2:5 and dump the summation in sheet1 . And the same has to be repeated for rows 2 to 5.

Comment: So it is a 4 X 4

Comment: Yes.. It is a 4x4 table.. let me edit the comment

Comment: If all you are doing is a `Sum` have you considered just using a formula in Excel, e.g. `=SUM(Sheet2:Sheet5!E6)`?

Comment: @YowE3K: I need to do that for tens of sheets and hundreds of rows and columns.. hence the macro part..

Comment: @ArunKumarNarasimhan I was basing my suggestion on your code which is just writing to **one** sheet (and the now accepted answer, which is also only processing one sheet), and you mentioned 5 rows and 5 columns, so it seems it would be easy enough to just write the formula in cell Summation!E6 and copy it to the other 5 x 5 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsSumry As Worksheet
    Dim startRow As Long, StartCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ar(1 To 4, 1 To 4) As Variant

    '~~> Start row and start column
    startRow = 2: StartCol = 2

    '~~> Summary sheet
    Set wsSumry = Sheet1

    '~~> Looping through each worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        '~~> Check if it is not the summary sheet
        If ws.Name <> wsSumry.Name Then
            '~~> Loop through the row and columns and
            '~~> Store it in an array
            For i = startRow To (startRow + 3)
                For j = StartCol To (StartCol + 3)
                   ar(i - 1, j - 1) = ar(i - 1, j - 1) + ws.Cells(i, j)
                Next j
            Next i
        End If
    Next

    '~~> Write array to summary sheet
    wsSumry.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(ar), UBound(ar)).Value = ar
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**[image]

Comment: this is more like I what I was looking for. I will look into what the nested loop does and if it achieves the purpose..

Comment: I modified your code to run for my problem for a larger data.. These are the modifications I did.. It's giving an error 91.. @SiddharthRout

Comment: What modifications?

Comment: I'm sorry I was traveling on a business trip and couldn't put time on this. The sheet, row and column ranges are modified. Sheets go from 7 to Sheets.Count, Row goes from 6 to 80, column goes from 4 to 23. I still want the same sort of addition as you mentioned earlier but the data has to be dumped in sheet5.     For x = 7 To myTotal
        If ws.Name <> wsSummation.Name Then
            For i = startRow To endRow
                For j = StartCol To endCol
                  ar(i, j) = ar(i, j) + ws.Cells(i, j) @SiddhartRout

Answer (score 0):

You can use Copy and Add technique, cycling through each sheet that isn't the summisary sheet and then pasting its values in to the final sheet (while adding them) - something like:

```
Dim b As Worksheet
Set b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    b.range("A1:A2").clear

For Each a In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not a.Name = b.Name Then
        a.Range("A1:A2").Copy
        b.Range("A1:A2").PasteSpecial operation:=xlAdd
    End If
Next
```

Obviously your range can be defined in place of "A1:A2"

I'm sure there's a more "code" way of adding arrays together but in Excel this might prove good for you.

Comment: I'm checking if it solves my problem.. will get back to you in a bit.. thanks.